# Replace @Query parameter with the value from a map

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following query

```
@Query("SELECT g.id as name FROM Group g")
List<Group> findGroups(Map<Long, String> groupNameMap)
```

I only have the id from entity Group.  And I want to map the id to the name using the groupNameMap.  I want to do something like the following

```
@Query("SELECT :groupNameMap[g.id] as name FROM Group g")
List<Group> findGroups(Map<Long, String> groupNameMap)
```

so that it will return a list of Group names instead of ids.  Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement that as a new method:

```
@Query("SELECT g.id as name FROM Group g")
List<Long> findGroups();

default List<Group> findGroups(Map<Long, String> groupNameMap) {
    return findGroups().stream()
        .map(id -> new Group(groupNameMap.get(id)))
        .collect(toList());
}
```